# Time and week start day in Thunderbird in Ubuntu 18

Tags: thunderbird, format, time

*Thunderbird in Ubuntu 18.04*

I did set 24hrs format in Ubuntu by settings - Date & Time - Time Format and I have correct time on the top of my screen.

However, I still have 12hrs format in Thunderbird 18.04 and my weeks start on Sunday. I can not find provision to set date and time format in Thunderbird itself. (I have no problems of this kind using Windows version of Thunderbird before)

Is there any simple way to fix this problem?

Following some other discussion I did check locale and it says: LC_Time="en_Ca.UTF-8"  - in the case of US it suppose to be 24 hrs (according to another chat on this webpage). I am in the process of learning Linux and, without GUI,I am little lost in deeper settings...

Few lines script what to do will be very helpful!

Regards, A.D.

Answer (score 1):

Open up your Thunderbird and locate the settings with `Edit --> Preferences --> Advanced` on the `Data and Time Formatting` select the first option to use you Ubuntu settings config for Time format.

[image]

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1228724

Comment: Thank you for suggestion - I have choice of English UK and English Canada. Either gives me 24 hr time format. May date is as I like (YYYY-MM-DD) - seems be Ubuntu setting. What about Config Editor?  Is there any listing & guidance available? I see calendar.timezone.local which in my case is set   " America/Toronto "  AD

Comment: I nearly found  it: activities - settings - Language and Regions   then: language=English (Canada in my case)  Formats=United Kingdom  With such a settings I have time in 24 hrs format, week starts with Monday. Penalty is that date format is dd/mm/yyyy.  I am looking further...